# Change html tag in template file tpl

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have this template file for a view:

```
views-view--ir-news--page.tpl.php
```

But right now, I need to use Google AMP only for this view (Machine name: ir_news)
What I want to know is if something like this it's possible:

```
html-views-view--ir-news.tpl.php
```

Because I need to change, for this view the html tag from this  to this  only for this view.

Is this possible? Is that the way?
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: which html tag? can you show in inspect element screenshot?

Comment: I need to implement the google amp tags, styles and scripts.
But, I don't want to use the amp theme, because I already have a theme (template), I need to include only the html amp tag, the metatags, the styles and the scripts.
This is a little hard for me for two reasons, first I don't understand very well drupal 7, and second, the most of the documentation it's on english and it's not my first language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use AMP for specific pages, you might want to take a look at the [AMP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/amp).

But if you still want to add the `amp` attribut to the `<HTML>` tag manually, here's one way:

Overwrite the `html.tpl.php` template by copying the original tpl file (modules/system/html.tpl.php) to your current theme (sites/all/themes/your_theme/). Then add the following code at the top of the file:

```
$amp = '';
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
    $nid = arg(1);
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $amp = $node->type == 'ir_news' ? 'amp' : '';
}
```

Then, you just print the $amp variable inside the `<html>` tag.

The `amp` attribute will only be added to your ir_news pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is my html.tpl.php

```
<?php global $base_url, $theme_path ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="<?= $language->language ?>" dir="<?= $language->dir ?>"<?= $rdf_namespaces, !empty($schemaorg) ? $schemaorg : ''; ?>>
    <head>
        <?= $head; ?>
        <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <title><?= $head_title; ?></title>
        <?= $styles; ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <?= $scripts; ?>
        <?php dri_config_output_gtm_head() ?>
    </head>
    <body class="<?= $classes; ?>" <?= $attributes; ?>>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is what I need exclusively for this view: *views-view--ir-news--page.tpl.php*

```
<?php global $base_url, $theme_path ?>
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
    <?php print $head; ?>
    <?php include $theme_path_file . '/templates/amp-css/amp-boilerplate-styles-min.inc' ?>
    <?php if (!empty($ampsubtheme_path_file)): ?>
      <style amp-custom>
        <?php include $theme_path_file . '/css/amp-custom-styles.css' ?>
      </style>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
  </body>
</html>
```

And finally I need to add this function for replace the img tag for a

```
function theme_image($variables) {
  // Remove RDF properties incompatible with AMP specification.
  if (isset($variables['attributes']['typeof'])) {
    unset($variables['attributes']['typeof']);
  }

  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
  $attributes['src'] = file_create_url($variables['path']);

  foreach (array('width', 'height', 'alt', 'title') as $key) {

    if (isset($variables[$key])) {
      if (empty($attributes[$key])) {
        $attributes[$key] = $variables[$key];
      }
    }
  }

  return '<amp-img' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '></amp-img>';
}
```

But I'm not sure if I can add this function to this file **views-view--ir-news--page.tpl.php** or it's only for the *template.php* file.

Thanks for the answers. Sorry for my english.